# How to create video recording intent with disabling specific camera controls?

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, video, camera

I want the app to capture video using only the rear camera , and to not allow filters or any other controls other that start recording and stop recording .

I am using intent to capture video in android and specify recording details such as :

```
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
```

And

```
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 15);
```

I am trying to disable the video controls using the same technique.

Is there a way to pass constants using Android.Hardware.Camera.CameraInfo via intent to disable front camera ?

For example if the below syntax is wrong , what is the correct syntax ?

```
    //disables front camera, so user cannot switch to front camera
    intent.putExtra(Camera.Camera_Facing_Front,0);
    //alows only back camera
    intent.putExtra(Camera.Camera_Facing_Back,1);
```

From Api:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html

And is it possible to disable video filters using Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters via intent ?

For example if the below syntax is wrong , what is the correct syntax ?

```
    //disable sepia filter, so user cannot choose it
    intent.putExtra(EFFECT_SEPIA,0);
```

From Api:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

In ios video controls can be removed simply via :

```
    self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

I am looking for something similar to this in android .

If this is not possible in android , is there a way to disable the front camera ? , so that when a user switch to front , the screen becomes blank ?

note: i am using Hardware.Camera NOT Hardware.Camera2.

Comment: implement your own activity to start camera and start recording

Comment: that is not an option at the moment . can you point out why this is not possible using intent , and what is wrong with the code in my question ?

Comment: by this type of intent, it can start only the inbuilt camera app or any other installed. so all the features of the camera will always available to the user, an intent cant modify the behavior of other app

Comment: but the intents i attached above (duration limit,video quality,start with front camera) are working .

Comment: if its working then effect should also work if not then its the limitation of the inbuilt camera app